# Question regarding an equation in a paper on parabolas

Tags: geometry

In this [paper on parabolas](https://www.academia.edu/12261571/A_Parabola_Symmetrical_to_y_x_line) by K. Kumar I was reading this morning I found an equation which I do not think I fully understand.

On page 489, part 4 (Derivation), the author defines the distance between the focus $C(x_1, y_1)$ of a parabola $P$ and the parabola itself to be equal to: $$\frac{|ax + by + c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$ where the expression above the division line defines a line by $ax+by+c=0$ (the directrix of the parabola) and the expression below is the square root of the sum of the squares of the coefficients of the line.

My question is: Why is this true? That is, why is the distance between the focus $C(x_1, y_1)$ of a parabola $P$ and the parabola itself equal to that expression? And consequently, what does the above expression represent, geometrically?

Comment: parabolas satisfy(defined by) the property that the points on it are equal distance from the focus(point) and the directrix(line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the paper. By definition, a parabola is the set of points such that the distance between the points and a fixed point $P$ and the distance between the points and a fixed line $ax+by+c=0$ are equal.

So the author set up this equation:

$$\frac{|ax + by + c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=\sqrt{(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2}$$

where left hand side is the distance between a point $(x,y)$ on the parabola and the line, the right hand side is the distance between that point on the parabola $(x,y)$ and the focus $(x_1,y_1)$.

Geometrically, it says in the following picture, line segments $1$ and $2$ have same lengths.

[image]